# Magento 2 - No Manufacturer or Brand attribute by default in Product

Tags: php, product, magento2

I need to use for my extension either a brand attribute or a manufacturer attribute in the products. Nevertheless, I cannot find any attribute that corresponds to that case.

For example, doing something like these returns nothing:

```
$this->_logger->debug(' Manufacturer ' . $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'));
```

And something like these:

```
$this->_logger->debug('Manufacturer ' .$product->getManufacturer());
```

raises an exception.

Am I missing something or it doesn't exist by default?

Comment: Adding some code would help. Even it's it's a simplified conceptualization of the problem; it would help.

Comment: did you enter values in product for these attributes ?

Comment: No, that is part of my question. I cannot see the field for  the attributes whenever I either edit or add a product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure that you have assigned "manufacture" or "brand" attribute
  to appropriate product Attribute Set.
- Make sure you have enter values manufacture or brand for the product
  as well.

You can get attribute text by using below code.

```
echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');

echo $_product->getAttributeText('brand');
```

if $_product doesn't work for you then try below code to get product data.

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
```

OR

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
```

Accept if this answer is helpful to you.

Source link [answered here as well](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/157334/38088)